# How to pass 2 lists to 1 view

Tags: list, asp.net-mvc-4, view, controller, webgrid

I want to show recent and incoming appointments in my view(one page).Here is my controller where can i add the second list and how can i pass it to same view?I know I cant return two list but there must be way for it?

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            if (Session["UserEmail"] != null) 
            {
                string Email = (string)Session["UserEmail"];

                using (var db = new MaindbModelDataContext())
                {
                    var patient = db.Patients.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == (String)Session["UserEmail"]);
                    ViewBag.FirstName = patient.Name;
                    ViewBag.LastName = patient.Surname;
                    ViewBag.BirthDate = patient.Birthday;
                    ViewBag.Email = patient.Email;


                }


                using (var db = new MaindbModelDataContext())
                {
                    var patient = db.Patients.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == (String)Session["UserEmail"]);
                    var listrecent = (from y in db.Appointments
                                      where y.PatientNo == patient.PatientNo
                                      where y.Date < DateTime.Today
                                      orderby y.Date descending
                                      select y).Take(5); 

                    var TempRecent = new List<Models.AppModel>();
                    foreach (var item in listrecent)
                    {
                        var Temp = new Models.AppModel();
                        Temp.AppNo = item.AppNo;
                        Temp.PatientNo = (Int32)item.PatientNo;
                        Temp.Date = (DateTime)item.Date;
                        Temp.Status = item.Status;
                        Temp.Description = item.Description;
                        TempRecent.Add(Temp);

                    }
                    return View(TempRecent);
                }

            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("RegAndLogin", "User");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

and here is my view part

```
@model IEnumerable<DentAppSys.Models.AppModel>
@using System.Web.Helpers

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}


    <section class="Patient-Dashboard">

        <div id="dashboard_left">
            <h1> Recent Appointments</h1>
   @{
    var Mygrid = new WebGrid(Model, selectionFieldName: "SelectedRow");
}

@Mygrid.GetHtml(
    displayHeader: true,

    mode: WebGridPagerModes.FirstLast,

columns: Mygrid.Columns
(

    Mygrid.Column("Appointment No", "Appointment No",format: @<text>@item.AppNo</text>),
    Mygrid.Column("Patient No", "Patient No", format: @<text>@item.PatientNo</text>) ,
    Mygrid.Column("Description", "Description", format: @<text>@item.Description</text>),
    Mygrid.Column("Date", "Date", format: @<text>@item.Date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")</text>),
    Mygrid.Column("Status", "Status", format: @<text>@item.Status</text>)

))
</div>

<div id="dashboard_right">
<br/>
<h1>Incoming Appointments</h1>

  /* HERE I WANT TO ADD MY SECOND LIST*/
</div>
</section>
```

**Edit:**

**and after using two instances of the AppModel I get error when I try to equal Temp.RecentIncoming.AppNo=item.AppNo.**

```
using (var db = new MaindbModelDataContext())
                {
                    var patient = db.Patients.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == (String)Session["UserEmail"]);
                    var listincoming = (from y in db.Appointments
                                      where y.PatientNo == patient.PatientNo
                                      where y.Date > DateTime.Today
                                      orderby y.Date descending
                                      select y).Take(5);

                    var TempIncoming = new List<Models.RecentIncoming>();
                    foreach (var item in listincoming)
                    {
                        var Temp = new Models.RecentIncoming.;
                        Temp.RecentIncoming.AppNo?????= item.AppNo;
                        Temp.PatientNo = (Int32)item.PatientNo;
                        Temp.Date = (DateTime)item.Date;
                        Temp.Status = item.Status;
                        Temp.Description = item.Description;
                        TempIncoming.Add(Temp);

                    }
                    return View(TempIncoming);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having IEnumerable as your model, create a new model class that has two instances of the AppModel as well as any other additional data you need to pass to the view...

```
public class MyAppointments
{
   public IEnumerable<DentAppSys.Models.AppModel> RecentAppts;
   public IEnumerable<DentAppSys.Models.AppModel> IncomingAppts;
   public MyAppointments() { }
}
...
return View( new MyAppointments() {  RecentAppts=TempRecent, IncomingAppts=TempIncoming       } );
```

Change the view to...

```
    @model MyAppointments
    ...
   @{
    var MyRecentgrid = new WebGrid(Model.RecentAppts, selectionFieldName: "SelectedRow");
    var MyIncomingGrid = new WebGrid(Model.IncomingAppts, selectionFieldName: "SelectedRow");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.I got error in this part new RecentIncoming() .The error is "Expected class,delegate,enum,interface or struct"...

Comment: In your code above, it was assumed that your recent appts and incoming appts will both be an IEnumerable of Models.AppModel.  So, where you have the error, create another Models.AppNo, not Models.RecentIncoming.  RecentIncoming is not a class, it is a variable in the view model that holds the IEnumerable<Models.AppModel> of the recent appts.  Also, you are passing this to a View, which I assume is the same view.  If you wanting to use the same view to show both recent and incoming, then create a single MyAppointments instance (class which you need to create using code as shown)....

Comment: (continued) and then create the IEnumerable values for both the recent and incoming and assign them to the MyAppointment instance.  Change your razor view model to MyAppointments and then access the separate variables for incoming and recent values.  Basically, to pass multiple values to a view, you need to create a single container model to hold them, you can't pass multiple values to a View (other than using ViewBag or TempData, which would not suggest for this solution).